# Cant connect to jupyter localhost for python

Tags: localhost, jupyter

I am trying to solve this problem for days when i try this is the error that i am getting :
This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 8888
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
please help i have try everything

Comment: You need to show your code and specifically where and when the error is occurring.

Comment: when i am entering  http://localhost:8888/?token=532db71088ff50437e3260a2d7cfe0d6ac8778444d5cb216

Comment: But you need to say what you are doing before; how are you running Jupyter ? Otherwise we can't tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have launched jupyter notebook from the command line within the terminal. and then it should automatically bring up jupyter notebooks within whatever is your default browser. If not try inputting http://localhost:8889/tree into your search bar. Please let me know if you need any more clarification or help!

Comment: i wanted to use Jupyter for python now that i can't run it i will use Intellij IDEA i tried what you told me but it doesn't seem to work anyway thank you.Do you thing that is any  disadvantage using intellij instead of jupyter

Comment: It works for me. I am using Windows 10, Open command prompt, and with Python in the Path, type at command prompt and type "jupyter-lab" (or "jupyter notebook" whatever version you installed). Something like C:\Users>jupyter-lab then enter.